# アノテーション @AssertTrue での入力値チェックが意図した通り動作しない

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

パスワード（pass）とパスワード再入力（reenter）が同じだった場合インサートが実行され、同じでない場合はエラーメッセージを表示してインサートしない、といったものを作っています。

しかし現状では、同じ値なのにエラーメッセージが出たり
お互い未入力なのにメッセージが出なかったり
といった感じです。

また、値が同じでエラーメッセージが表示されず（成功かな？）と思いそのまま値を別(reenterとpassをバラバラの値)にして再度登録を押すと、本来エラーメッセージが出るはずなのに出なかったりと訳が分かりません。

前提としてインサートは問題なく行えています。

教授していただきたく思います。

```
import javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue; 
@Getter
@Setter
public class CreateForm {
    @NotBlank
    private String id;
    @NotBlank
    private String pass;
    @NotBlank
    private String reenter;
    @AssertTrue(message = "PASSが一致しません")
        public boolean isCheck() {
            if (pass != reenter) return true;
                return false;
        }
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @NotBlank
    private String kana;
    @NotBlank
    private String birth;
    @NotBlank
    private String club;
}
```

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/create}" th:object="${createForm}" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="id" th:field="*{id}"><br>
                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('id')}" th:errors="*{id}"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>pass</th>
            <!-- ポイント2 -->
            <td><input type="text" name="pass" th:field="*{pass}"><br>
                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('pass')}" th:errors="*{pass}"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>reenter</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="reenter" th:field="*{reenter}"><br>
                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('reenter')}"
                th:errors="*{reenter}"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('check')}"
                th:errors="*{check}"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" th:field="*{name}"><br>
                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>kana</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="kana" th:field="*{kana}"><br>
                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('kana')}" th:errors="*{kana}"></span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>birth</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="birth" th:field="*{birth}"><br>
                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('birth')}" th:errors="*{birth}"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>club</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="club" th:field="*{club}"><br>
                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('club')}" th:errors="*{club}"></span></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="登録">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@GetMapping("create")
String create(@ModelAttribute CreateForm customerForm) {
    return "create";
}

@PostMapping("create")
String regist(@Validated @ModelAttribute CreateForm createForm,
    BindingResult result,
    Model model) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return create(createForm);
    }
    User user = new User();
    Userdetail userdetail = new Userdetail();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(createForm, user);
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(createForm, userdetail);
    sevi.insert(user);
    sevi.insert2(userdetail);

    return "redirect:/create";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java の文字列比較は `==`( や `!=` )でなく [`String#equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) メソッドや [`Objects.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object))メソッドを用います。

おそらく意図している実装は次のものではないでしょうか。

```java
import java.util.Objects;
// ...

  @AssertTrue(message = "PASSが一致しません")
  public boolean isCheck() {
    return Objects.equals(pass, reenter);
  }
```

関連:

- [Javaの文字列の比較について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/24297/2808)
- [String型を==で比較したときの挙動が予想と違う](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/63088/2808)

Comment: DEWA Kazuyuki - 出羽和之　の回答で解決致しました！ありがとうございました！